# How to check if cvxpy's solve() is successful?

Tags: cvxpy

This my first time trying to use cvxpy. I have 2 very simple constrains:

```
x = cp.Variable((5, 5))
constrains = [cp.sum(x) == 1.0, 0 <= x]
```

The solution worked most of time, satisfying both constrains. But sometimes the solution only satisfied the first constrain and spit out negative values. I am wondering if there is a way to have the solver to indicate whether it has succeeded or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of information is always part of some status-information filled by the solver. In cvxpy's case this is documented [here](https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.problems.html#cvxpy.problems.problem.Problem.status):

So something like:

```
problem.solve()
if problem.status == 'optimal':
    ...
else:
    ...
```

is the usual route.

### Remark:

The solver decides this and feasibility and optimality decisions are depending on tolerances in general (floating-point math!).

Furthermore, most solvers within cvxpy are interior-point like solvers (some even first-order based solvers) which slowly converge to some arbitrarily accurate approximate solution such that:

- your simplex-constraint (`sum(x) == 1`) might be off (compared to 1.0) by some small epsilon like `1e-12`
- some non-negative variable might be negative by some small epsilon like `1e-12`

This is totally normal (for these kinds of solvers; things are different when using simplex-like solvers or simplex-based crossover post-opt). The user needs to take care and the approach he is chosing usually depends on his use-case. E.g. post-clipping `x = np.clip(x.value, 0.0, np.inf)`, rounding and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For me `problem.status == 'optimal'` didn't work, it said it was optimal when the constraints were not met. This worked better.

```
    result = prob.solve()
    if np.isnan(result):
        print('no solution found')
```

Comment: That might work if the solver failed or the problem is infeasible/unbounded but even in that case it is much better to use the status.

Comment: well it said `problem.status == 'optimal'` even when it was infeasible